# Unable to create web-components by using vue-cli and vue3

Tags: web-component, vuejs3

I am trying to get web-components work inside vue3 project.

I did following steps. (Try to make super simple way)

1. I made a new project on vue-cli.
2. I chose vue3 preview.
3. After that I tried to execute script, which should generate web-components from existing project components.
   `vue-cli-service build --target wc-async 'src/components/*.vue'`

I get following error:

```
 error  in ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=template&id=0dfd15f1&bindings={"label":"props"}?shadow

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 17

    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.TemplateLoader (C:\git\vue-tests\footest\node_modules\vue-loader-v16\dist\templateLoader.js:37:154)

 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=template&id=0dfd15f1&bindings={"label":"props"}?shadow 1:0-424 1:0-424
 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?shadow
 @ ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/entry-wc.js
```

I tested this scenario with vue2 starting template and everything works. Is there something what I dont understand correctly or is it so that this is not working with vue3.